# 1.0 g of AlCl3 is added to 100.0 ml of water. What would be the resulting pH?

Tags: acid-base, water, ph

> $1.0\ \mathrm g$ of $\ce{AlCl3}$ is added to $100.0\ \mathrm{ml}$ of water. What would be the resulting pH?

I think the answer may be $4.022$ but I'm not certain.

The reaction wasn't provided but I think its this:
$$\ce{Al(H2O6)6^3+ <=> H^+ + Al(H2O)5(OH)^2+}$$
Assuming all $\ce{Al}$ dissolved in water:
Initial $[\ce{Al}]=7.49\times10^{-4}\ \mathrm M$

$$x^2/(7.49\times10^{-4}-x)=1.4\times10^{-5}$$

$$x=9.56\times10^{-5}$$

$$\mathrm{pH}=-\log(9.56\times10^{-5})=4.022$$

Comment: What happened to the Cl attached to the Al?!?

Comment: I have no idea, I'm so confused with this question

Comment: I think you have the right idea, but in an excess of water the overall reaction would be $$\ce{AlCl3 + 6H2O ->[aqueous] Al(H2O)5(OH)^{2+} + H+ + 3Cl-(aq)}$$

Comment: Oh okay. Do you know how to solve this

Comment: Assume volume of solution is the same as the volume of water and that the reaction I gave goes to 100% completion.

Comment: So assume all Al dissolved in water

Comment: Yes there will be an excess of water. 100ml of water is about 5.5 moles of water.

Comment: can you confirm if 4.022 is right

Comment: No. Add your work as an answer. I'll comment on it to help you get it right, then you can accept your answer and gain some site reputation. // Start with the chemical equation. You can edit your post to see the markup I did.

Comment: okay I've shown my work

Comment: Your first mistake is "$\pu{[inital] Al} = \pu{7.49\cdot10^{-4}}$. Please show how you got that value.

Answer (score 1):

Not being given any other information assume the reaction goes to completion and that it is:

$$\ce{AlCl3 + 6H2O ->[excess H2O] Al(H2O)5(OH)^{2+} + H+ +3Cl-}$$

molecular mass $\ce{AlCl3 = \pu{133.34 g/mol}}$. So:

$$\ce{\pu{mol AlCl_{3}} = mol [Al(H2O)_5OH^{2+}] = mol [H+]} = \frac{\pu{1 g}}{\pu{133.34 g/mol}} = \pu{7.496\cdot 10^{-3} mol}$$

$$\pu{Molarity} = \dfrac{\pu{moles}}{\pu{volume}} = \dfrac{\pu{7.496\cdot 10^{-2} mol}}{\pu{0.100 L}} = \pu{0.07496 M}$$

pH = - log(0.07496) = 1.12

---

Now the truth is a bit more complicated. You can assume the reaction happens in two steps. The first step will go to completion.

$$\ce{AlCl3 + 6H2O ->[excess H2O] Al(H2O)6^{3+}  +3Cl-}$$

The second step won't go to completion since $\ce{Al(H2O)6^{3+}}$ is a weak acid. There will be an equilibrium favoring the left side. But with no value for $K_\mathrm{eq}$ you are stymied.

$$\ce{Al(H2O)6^{3+} ->[excess H2O] Al(H2O)5(OH)^{2+} + H+}$$

$$K_\mathrm{eq} =\dfrac{\ce{[H+][Al(H2O)5(OH)^{2+}]}}{\ce{[Al(H2O)6^{3+}]}}$$

Comment: oh ok? I'm very confused at this point

Comment: @nanxii - Sorry I fouled that up badly.

Comment: i'm kinda desperate at this point. I just need a simple explanation and answer

Comment: @nanxii - Since I messed up, I'll just give an answer. But this isn't a homework site. You've gotten a free ride on two questions. Don't expect more. See the site's [homework policy](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/q/141/22102).

Comment: Actually the OP has stated an equilibrium constant. The only problem i see is the miscalculation of the molarity. If we use the correct value you can calculate the pH assuming the first step goes to completition. (Wich is 3.0 considering the rounding for given significant digits.)